# Stitching hole in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a 3D array, in the center of which there is a chunk of NaN values. Is there any way (in MATLAB) to stitch this hole with something like a spline?

An easy 2D array-example would be:

```
Z = peaks;
Z(20:30,20:30) = NaN;
```

Stitch the hole in Z with a surface.

Comment: well i think the first step is for you to decide how you want the hole stitched - ie do you know the underlying mathematical model that generates the array disregarding the hole? If you do you can reevaluate that model to fill the hole. otherwise, you have to make the decision anyway

Comment: I do, actually, but I would rather not use it. The thing is, that the array describes some function which has a peak at the center, and then some wide, slowly varying stuff elsewhere. I want to remove the peak, so I will actually be filling in the NaN-values myself.

Comment: makes sense, in that case seeing as either way it makes no mathematical sense, the filling method is up to you - if you can better describe the "shape" of the filling im sure someone can give you a close function

Comment: if you are only interested in the wide parts, I'd take the maximum value adjacent to an NaN and fill the NaNs with that value. This will be within the scale of the interesting parts and quite easy to compute. Or just pick any number adjacent to an NaN

Answer (score 2):

There is one excellent submission on the File Exchange, [inpaint_nans](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551), which will fill in the NaNs for you - here in an image, but works for any 2D array ([here's the 3D version](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21214))

[image]